# How to use ActiveXObject in Angular 4 project

Tags: angular, typescript, activexobject

I am trying to use ActiveXObject like below

```
getActiveXObject(pdfCtrl) {
      return new ActiveXObject(pdfCtrl);
    }

    checkPDF() {
        let plugin = null;
            if (this.getBrowser() === 'ie') {
                plugin = this.getActiveXObject('AcroPDF.PDF') || this.getActiveXObject('PDF.PdfCtrl');
        }
        return plugin;
    }
```

It gives error like ActiveXObject not found. In plain JS this works, but in Angular/typesript compilation phase it throws error. How do i handle this?

Comment: *'it throws error'* - this tells us nothing! Please specify what error it is that you're getting.

Comment: Also, I'd very, very heavily recommend avoiding ActiveX unless you have no other choice. It's not supported in any modern browsers, and there's native JS libraries like PDF.js which will do the same job.

Comment: ActiveXObject not found is the error thrown.

Comment: Any news on this question? I'm facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

example for msxml - ActiveXObject is available only in IE, in Chrome using native methods:

```js
 import * as ts from "typescript";
 ...
  private loadMsXml(src: string): any {
    let code: string = `({
      Run: (data: string): any => {
        let doc = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0");
        doc.async = false;
        doc.loadXML(data);
        return doc;
      })`;
    const e = eval;
    let result = ts.transpile(code);
    let runnalbe: any = e(result);
    return runnalbe.Run(src);
  }

  private transformXml(xmlDoc: any, xsltDoc: any): string {
    if (this.isBrowserIE()) {
      let xmlDocMS = this.loadMsXml(new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(xmlDoc));
      let xslDocMS = this.loadMsXml(new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(xsltDoc));
      let resultXml = xmlDocMS.transformNode(xslDocMS);
      return resultXml;
    }

    let xsltProcessor = new XSLTProcessor();
    xsltProcessor.importStylesheet(xsltDoc);
    let resultDoc = xsltProcessor.transformToDocument(xmlDoc);
    let resultXml = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(resultDoc);
    return resultXml;
  }
```